# Data entry form that selects the next open row per specified column in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a data entry form that submits data to a data sheets first open row. The problem is that the data sheet has formula in one of the columns so it is not truly empty. This is causing the current script to take the cells with formula into consideration and only selecting the rows after it.

Could you guys please assist me with a workaround to the issue.

Current script looks like this:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("FORM"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA"); //Data Sheet

  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("D4").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("D8").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("D12").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("D16").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("D20").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("D24").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("D28").getValue(),
  formSS.getRange("L32").getValue()]];

  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 8).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand `This is causing the current script to take the cells with formula into consideration and only selecting the rows after it.`.  Do you want to set your values into the first empty row - even if this row contains a formula?

Comment: Yes the form populates the data sheets column A to H and K. Column I has a formula in that calculates the amount of days a job has been outstanding. The formula should take the data that is being populated and calculating the mentioned information. But as it is now the formula is seen as an occupied cell and the script selects the next row below it. I can send a copy of the document if that would help clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

### You can find the first free row by evaluating the row contents

Sample

```js
 var freeRow;
 var columnI = datasheet.getRange("I1:I" + datasheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
for(var i = 0; i < columnI.length; i++){
  if(columnI[i] == "") {
    freeRow = i + 1;
    break;
  }
}
datasheet.getRange(freeRow, 1, 1, 8).setValues(values);
```

**In addition, you are using a `Form submit` trigger, you use [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)**

Sample

```js
function submitData(e) {
 var range = e.range;
 var row = range.getRow();
 // this is the row into which the latest form response has been inserted - do with it what you need
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah wow that worked great. I am trying to understand exactly how it works though. Could you please explain it to me. (Sorry, i am still learning)

Comment: The code loops through all cells of column I and checks their content. If the content is empty (`columnI[i] == ""`), the row is considered to be free. I suggest you to have a look at the [Apps Script tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and the [method reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to gain a deeper understanding.